# What View subclass has include?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When I use `include` in a layout, I have to set width and height both to `include` tag and to the layout it is linked to. Otherwards it won't work correctly. So, it seems, that `include` is not a link, but a subclass of View, if it has its own width, height, id and so on. But on [developer's site](http://developer.android.com) there is not such class as `include`. Who are you, Mr. `include`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<include>` tag can be thought of as a copy/paste of the internal layout.  It's part of the xml parsing that's in the View `Inflater` classes.  It effectively takes the layout ID, inflates the xml object you pass in, then adds it to the main layout that it's inflating based on the attributes of the included layout.  You can use it on anything that inherits from `View`.

You can overwrite any of the attributes that have `layout_` in them.  You don't *have* to overwrite the width and height attributes if they are included in the root of the layout your including.  **However**, you **do** have to overwrite those parameters if you are overwriting any other attribute.  It's part of a bug in how `<include>` is parsed.  If you want to change, say, `layout_marginLeft`, you would have to overwrite `layout_width` and `layout_height` to the same values that are in the layout in order for the parser to overwrite the left margin attribute.

Comment: "However, you do have to overwrite those parameters if you are overwriting any other attribute. " Yes, I see now. That was the problem - I tried to place them and thus "cancelled" all layout parametres...

Comment: So, if I want to make some parametres in include common for all include's, I have to add a root layout in the internal layout?

Comment: @Gangnus in the **included** layout, yes (hope that's what you meant by "internal").

Comment: Sorry, but I have set the margings and centering in the include tag. And it was not sizing that didn't work, but placing. ... OK, if it is a bug, it could work any way.

Comment: @Felix I merely used the term of DeeV... Yes, "included" sounds better

Comment: Yeah, that bug killed my productivity for days because I couldn't figure out why some of my magrins weren't being set while other were.  I finally found a bug report that said the inflater throws a silent exception when the width and height parameters aren't set but you're trying to overwrite the others.  Also remember that the only parameters that can be overwritten are the parameters beginning with `layout_` in them in the included layout's root.  Padding, alpha, background, translations, etc. must be set in the included layout itself.

Answer (score 1):

`include` doesn't actually need a width and height if you specify the width and height of the root element of the included layout. In other words, this is entirely valid:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_included_layout" />
```

So long as `my_included_layout` has a root element with a width and height it will be happy.

Comment: Sorry. An hour ago I have had a meeting with a colleague from another firm. Independently we came to the fact, that without setting both include *and* the referenced layout width and height the placing of the include won't work. Neither in his nor my layouts. I have seen this guy for the first time in my life and I incline to trust thoughts that have been checked by independent tester positively.

Comment: Fair enough. I currently have 39 includes in just my open project alone and I'm not specifying width or height in any of them. I can assure you that mine are being placed appropriately. Not sure what you guys are doing, but perhaps post an example?

Comment: DeeV in another answer explained the cause. It is a bug :-(. But thank you and +1, for your example IS correct.

Comment: Thanks and good luck. I learned a bit more about `include` today too :).

Comment: I only don't understand - if my questions are so useful, why I hardly have a plus for them? Maybe, it is the problem of language? Answer are OK, though.